# BufferedImage pixel scan leaves white spaces

Tags: java, image

Iam scanning pixels of 2 different `bufferedImages`. The first one is a screenshot of my desktop. The second one is a custom image I am choosing on the start. If the pixel color on the first image (screenshot) is white, I am drawing the color on it, which the second bufferedImage has on this position. My problem is, that sometimes it leaves white spaces. But everytime it is the same pattern. (See on the images). 
Short explanation: I am drawing a bufferedImage on my screen.

I already tried removing a lot of queryies which could cause this problem, but it is weird because everytime it leaves the white space on the same position... I checked the white spaces and the Color was white.

I am drawing the image with different layers so it looks more realistic and draws faster. I think that it has problems sometimes with scanning small pixels. If I only draw the image in 1 layer there are no white spaces.

```java
while (i < width) {
    if (i == width - 1 && j < height - 1) {
    j ++;
    i = 0;
}

if((red == 255 && green == 255 && blue == 255)) {
    if (ScanWrite.cancel == false) {
        drawIt(i, j);
    }
}
```

That should be fully black:

[image]

Here you can see that it is the same pattern:
[image]

Comment: not sure what you are saying here

Comment: Perhaps the alpha channel needs to also be considered here.